# Global variable declaration issue

Tags: java

I have global variable `private int temp=0;`. In the class it is incrementing (At some what stage say it is temp=10).When again loading the class temp is still 10. But I need it 0. How can I do that?

code:

```
public class MyClass
{
private int temp = 0;

  public void method1() // while calling this method temp increments say temp =1;
  {
  temp++;
  }

  public void method2()
  {
  if(temp == 0)
  System.out.println("temp = "+temp):
  }
}
```

After this suppose `temp = 10`, and when loading `MyClass` still `temp=10`, but I need `temp=0` again. Since I'm new to programming I don't know whether it make sense.

Comment: There is no such thing as loading a class, you probably meant you create an instance of the class.

And temp is not a global variable, but a member of the class. Please read about class members.

Comment: Do you mean that you do something like: MyClass mc = new MyClass(); and it's still 10 ?!

Comment: I need a an integer value temp, should be zero, whenever calling the class. Whatever it was in the previous call.

Comment: What do you mean "calling the class"? if you mean creating a new instance it will always be initialized with 0. Show us are you going to use this class

Answer (score 1):

temp is *always* going to be 0 unless it is declared as static.

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.method1() // 'temp' of mc object is now 1
MyClass mc2 = new MyClass();
mc2.method2() //'temp' of mc2 object is still 0!
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant by *loading the class*, *calling the class* etc

Note that **each new instance of the class will give you `temp = 0`** and If you mean within the same instance,See this example, I added a new method, `method0()`

```
public class MyClass
{
private int temp = 0;

  public void method0()
  {
    temp = 0;
  }

  public void method1()
  {
  temp++;
  }

  public void method2()
  {
  if(temp == 0)
  System.out.println("temp = "+temp):
  }
}
```

In this case,

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.method2();
mc.method1();
mc.method2();
mc.method0();
mc.method2();
```

Will give you,

```
temp = 0
//Incremented value of temp
//condition if(temp==0) fails
//reset value of temp
temp = 0
```

Hope this is what you meant.cheers.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to re-initialize temp to 0 every time you create a new object of the class - MyClass.

If this is what you want, then make use of a constructor. And initialise temp to 0 in the constructor.

```
 public MyClass 
 {   
        temp = 0; 
 }
```

This way, every time you create a new object of MyClass, temp will be set back to 0.

Comment: This is not required. temp will always be initialized to 0 when creating a new object of MyClass.